# -webkit-transition-timing-function doesn't have any effect in Chrome

Tags: css, css-transitions

No matter what I set the `-webkit-transition-timing-function` I always get the default `ease` behavior.
I have tried all the options and need the `linear`, but Chrome ignores the setting. 
FF and Safari do work as expected...

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

```
 .boxOverGlow
    {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        z-index: 28;
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);


        transition-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear; /* Firefox 4 */

    -o-transition-timing-function: linear; /* Opera */

     transition:opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:opacity 1s; /* Opera */

     -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; /* Safari and Chrome */


    }
```

Comment: There must be something else wrong with your particular case because the linear timing function works here in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ryjQH/

Answer (score 1):

when you are changing the behavior, also change it for the default line i.e,

```
 transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
```

and these transitions are woking in my google chrome(20.0.1132).

you are using

```
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d
```

it is for the transfomation of elements which is totally different from transitions. try removing that line. according to what i understood from your question, i don't its necessary there. :)